# calculate measurement error of morphological measurements in R

Tags: r, measurement, anova

I know that to calculate measurement error in need to use an ANOVA, but i'm not sure how to implement in R

Data organised in the following mannder (with last line being a repeat measure):

```
ID  Wing    Tail    Tarsus  Mid Toe Culmen Depth    Culmen Width
A1  187    124.9    30      27.1    14.4               21
A2  185    130.4    28.5    27.4    13.9              18.5
A3  188    129.7    26.8    26.3    14.3              16.5
A3  189    126      26.9    25.6    13.8              15.9
```

How would I use an ANOVA in R to calculate percentage measurement error in R?

Thanks

Comment: Are these all measurements on the same object? And it would help further if you supplied the definition of "measurement error", since different scientific domains have difference "units of error". Some use coefficient of variation, others might use a raw standard deviation.

Comment: Are you looking trying to calculate repeatability (i.e., intraclass correlation coefficient)? If so, a couple of packages on r-forge might be helpful:   https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=738 and https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1004 Also, the abd package has a repeatability function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation of measurement error is based on an estimate of how large are the random deviations in the average of the measured property.

This error can be estimated by calculating the standard deviation of each property using `stats::sd()` function and dividing by $\sqrt(n)$ to get the measurement error of the average.